# beginSheetForDirectory to beginSheetModalForWindow

Tags: macos, xcode4.5

I'm updating some old code for post-10.6.

The code includes a save-time method that has about 60 lines of code in it, and is called from about 1/2 dozen places. The code used beginSheetForDirectory, which is no longer supported since 10.7.

I'm very confused how to convert the former @selector based solution to the new ^(NSInteger) form. All of the examples I can find use an inline-block, and I'm confused how to make that call a separate method.

The save method has this sig, and x is not used internally:

```
- (void)savePanelDidEnd:(NSOpenPanel *)sheet 
        returnCode:(int)returnCode 
       contextInfo:(void *)x
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this in another thread. The trick is to call beginSheetForDirectory with no return handler, then immediately call runModal on it. When runModal returns, process the dialog as normal.